# Find the maximum value of $x^2y^3$ subject to the condition that $3x+2y=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I am trying to use G.M.$\leq $ A.M.as follows

$(\frac{2x^2y^3}{4})^\frac{1}{5} \leq \frac{x+2x+y+\frac{y}{2} +\frac{y}{2}}{5}$

$\implies (\frac{x^2y^3}{2})^\frac{1}{5} \leq \frac{1}{5}$

$\implies$ $x^2y^3\leq \frac{2}{5^5}$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: No it is not correct. First of all it does not say $x$ is positive. What if $x = - 20000$? In fact, there is no maximum.

Comment: Also when applying AM-GM, always find the point at which the equality occurs. It may so happen that the equality cannot be reached.

Comment: Then how can it  be solved?

Comment: I just said there is no maximum. Just check what happens as $x \to - \infty$

Comment: yes, I got it. Thank you

Comment: @Math Even if the numbers are assumed to be positive, what you get is an upper bound, not the maximum. It cannot be attained, since the AM-GM equality case is when all terms are equal, but the way you chose them it's not possible for $\,x=2x=y=y/2\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive $x$ and $y$, you may use AM-GM:

$$\frac{1}{5}=\frac{3x+2y}{5}=\frac{\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{2y}{3}+\frac{2y}{3}+\frac{2y}{3}}{5}\ge \sqrt[5]{\frac{2}{3}x^2y^3}$$

From where one gets $x^2y^3\le\frac{3}{2\cdot 5^5}=\frac{3}{6250}$

The equality takes place when $\frac{3x}{2}=\frac{2y}{3}$, which coupled with $3x+2y=1$ yields $x=\frac{2}{15}$ and $y=\frac{3}{10}$

But of course, the general method (not precalculus level as tagged) to solve this optimization problem is by using [the method of Lagrange Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

As others noted, if we omit $x,y>0$ there is no global maximum.